# pass setProperty to inner object's setProperty

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

I have a UserPass class which has 2 properties: User user; String password
User has other properties like username, systemId etc.

I have a call to setProperty ("username", value) on UserPass, which should actually set the property of the User that is inside the UserPass.

Can someone suggest how this can be done? I have looked at PropertyUtils from apache commons beanutils by get the following on: PropertyUtils.setProperty(UserPass.getUser(), "username", value), but this throws an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No bean specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the instance of the UserPass object. The way you are doing it makes it look as if you are calling a static method on the class to getUser(). Say you have a UserPass declared as up like this:

```
  UserPass up = new UserPass();
  //set the various properties including the User object
```

then

```
 PropertyUtils.setProperty(up.getUser(), "username", value);
```

will work but only if getUser() returns a non-null object.